# Magento Patch 8788 on Magento 1.8.1.0 problem

Tags: magento-1.8, patches

I am trying to install the security patch 8788 but I get some errors.

```
patching file js/mage/adminhtml/product.js
patching file js/mage/adminhtml/uploader/instance.js
can't find file to patch at input line 5810
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git lib/Unserialize/Parser.php lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
|index 423902a..2c01684 100644
|--- lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
|+++ lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 5822
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php
|index caa979e..cd37804 100644
|--- lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php
|+++ lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 5838
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php
|index d2a4937..c6c0221 100644
|--- lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php
|+++ lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php
--------------------------
File to patch:
```

The whole lib/Unserialize folder does not exists. The shop of my client is running Magento 1.8.1.0 I have another client with the exact same thing, I also downloaded the correct file. And tried earlier patches too to see if some of them maybe created those folders but I could not really find anything. I would appreciate if somebody can point me in the right direction or has solved this problem before.

Comment: Looks like patch 6788 was not installed properly

Comment: Great advice @wesley. Adding 6788 before 8788 worked for me, thanks. Note that it was for a 1.8.0.0 site, not 1.8.0.1, but that shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make it an actual answer, I'll copy the comment with the answer here on behalf of the OP.

To make sure that `SUPEE-8788` works properly, you should have installed some of the earlier patches. In this case, `SUPEE-6788` wasn't installed. After installing that one before installing `SUPEE-8788`, the issue was solved.